# gstreamer srt relay crashs after adding tee

Tags: gstreamer

The goal is to deliver codec/format agnostic SRT (Secure reliable transport) relay,which takes one source URI and streams into multiple URIs. For one pipeline `srtsrc -> queue -> srtsink` works fine but we need to dynamically config multiple sinks. For splitting we use `tee` but after using this element pipeline starts and crashs after that, giving this error `EID:3 no sockets to check, this would deadlock`. The graph is provided below.

Is this pipeline

[image: pipeline graph:]